# Css issue in iPad

Tags: css, ipad

I have a Web site which is working very fine. But when i am trying to use in the ipad it's giving me the scroll to the Right hand side. The site is not live so i am not able to give you the URL

I have used width: 953px for the container and i don't have used any width for the Body part.

> Workaround

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=953px"/>

<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

> HTML

```
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="firstcontainer">
        <div class="h1-fonts">
            We understand your success
        </div>
        <div class="first-innertex">
            <p>Our planning consultancy is built around our people. We recruit, develop and retain the best professionals. We build strong relationships with our clients to with</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="button" onclick="location = '/team'" class="buttonred button-fonts" value="Meet the team" />
    </div>
    <div class="secondcontainer">
        <img src='/media/1004/success_people.png' width="555px" height="368px" alt='Banner Alt text' />
    </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.firstcontainer {   
    width: 38%;
    top: 147px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}    

.secondcontainer {    
    float: right;
}

.maincontainer {
    border: 1px solid #E2DEDE;
    height: 368px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.button-red {
    font-size: 16.18px;
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-style: solid;
    background-image: url('../images/arrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 97;
    padding-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(182, 39, 29);
    background-position: 90% 50%;
}
```

I have tried to put both of the thing but it's still not working.

**Note: I don't want to change my css**

If anyone can suggest me for this.

Comment: Can you provide the css code? Its pretty hard to guess what is going wrong on your page. Maybe you need some ``overflow hidden``? Or there is an element which you cant see, that is pointing out of the container und gives you the scrollable area.

Comment: @DerVampyr, I have edited the code plz check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change meta tag and it's worked nicely.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.8; maximum-scale=1.5;" />
```

I have change `initial-scale` to `0.8` from `1.0`. So It's reducing the zoom in the iPad and my site working very well without using any css

Answer (score 0):

It is very tricky to answer without the code, but the width of an iPad is 768px in portrait view, using 953px for your container will make it wider than the device size and therefore you will get the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with % on mobile devices

Comment: I Dont want to create mobile site just want to implement current layout in iPad

Answer (score 0):

The width of an ipad is 768px.

So you need to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=768px"/>`

And if you want a proper alignment you should give the img an %-width like this:

```
.secondcontainer {    
  float: right;
  width: 55%;
}

.secondcontainer img {    
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it will take lot of efforts to work with but i got another site which is working very fine without using any of the thing (Does not contain any meta tag and all). romans.co.uk are you able to explain me how it this working?